# Map doesn't contain key stored with put method java

Tags: java

I have some cars that run on generic roads.

`Cars` can be `Yellow` or `white`, each car has an unique `id` owned by the subclass (yellow or white).

`Road` contains one car and a starting point and an arrive. Each point is a `Coordinate` (int x, int y).

Then I have a method that takes a `List` of `Roads` and returns a `map`.
Map key is the car that appears in each road, map value is a `Set` with all the roads run by that car.

My problem is that after `put` cars into the map, `get` method return null so basically it doesn't find the car inserted one second ago.

These are all classes (it's a little long but easy) :

```
public class Coordinate{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public Coordinate() {
        x=0;
        y=0;
    }
}

public abstract class Car implements Comparable<Car>{
     public abstract int getId();
     
     @Override
     public int compareTo(Car c) {
         int ret = this.getId()-c.getId();
         if(ret==0) return 1;
         return ret;
     }
}

public class Yellow extends Car{
    private static int classId;
    private int id;
    public Yellow() {
        this.id=classId;
        classId++;
    }
    
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    
}

public class White extends Car{
    private static int classId;
    private int id;
    public White() {
        this.id=classId;
        classId++;
    }
    
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
}

public class Road implements Comparable<Road>{
    Car car;
    Coordinate start;
    Coordinate arrive;
    public Road(Car newCar) {
        car = newCar;
        start = new Coordinate();
        arrive = new Coordinate();
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Road o) {
        return 1;
    }
    
}
```

This is the class with the method that takes a list and returns a map.

```
public class DoSomething{
    
    public DoSomething() {
        
    }
    
    Map<Car,Set<Road>> listRoadToMap(List<Road> roadsList){
        Map<Car,Set<Road>> car2roads = new TreeMap<>();
        for(Road r : roadsList) {
            Car c = r.car;
            if(car2roads.containsKey(c)) {
                car2roads.get(c).add(r);
            }
            else {
                TreeSet<Road> setR = new TreeSet<>();
                setR.add(r);
                car2roads.put(c, setR); 
            }
        }
        return car2roads;
    }
}
```

This is `JUnitTestCase` :

```
class test {

    private DoSomething ds = new DoSomething();

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

    }
    
    @Test
    public void testTragittoPerAuto() {
        Yellow y1 = new Yellow();
        Yellow y2 = new Yellow();
        Yellow y3 = new Yellow();
        White  w1 = new White();
        
        Road r1 = new Road(y1);
        Road r2 = new Road(y2);
        Road r3 = new Road(y3);
        Road r4 = new Road(w1);
        List<Road> ris = new ArrayList<>();
        ris.add(r1);
        ris.add(r3);
        ris.add(r2);
        ris.add(r4);
        Map<Car,Set<Road>> car2road = new TreeMap<>();
        assertTrue(ds!=null);
        car2road = this.ds.listRoadToMap(ris);
        Set<Car> setCar= new TreeSet<>();
        setCar = car2road.keySet();
        for(Car a : setCar) System.out.print( a.getClass().getSimpleName().toString() + a.getId() + "\n" );
        assertNotNull(car2road);
        assertFalse(car2road.isEmpty());
        assertTrue(setCar.contains(y1));
        assertTrue(car2road.containsKey(y2));
        assertTrue(car2road.containsKey(y3));
        assertTrue(car2road.get(y1).contains(r1));
        assertTrue(car2road.get(y2).contains(r2));
        assertTrue(car2road.get(y3).contains(r3));
    }


}
```

It fails on line `assertTrue(setCar.contains(y1))` but this is the output of `for(Car a : setCar) System.out.print( a.getClass().getSimpleName().toString() + a.getId() + "\n" );` that gets all the cars and prints its `class`+`id`.

Output :

```
Yellow0
White0
Yellow1
Yellow2
```

This is weird because when I get all the keys it finds 4 keys, 3 yellow and one white with all ids but when I want to get them I have a failure.

Any idea?

Comment: Your comparator violates the contract. Always returning 1 is not a valid comparator. It says A becomes before B and B comes before A, which is a paradox. It's one or the other. Any unusual behaviour with TreeMap stems from that paradox.

Comment: @Michael I wasn't interested on ordering so I rushed. I didn't know this aspect need to study more comparators. What I should do to fix this? Just finding a way  to create e real order?

Comment: @user15793316 What is hard for me is to understand this problem, because I had no clue on what wrong I was doing

Comment: If you're not interested in ordering, don't use a TreeMap. Use an unordered map

Comment: @Michael you're right, I'm new in Java so I didn't think about it...Next time I'll use HashMap

Comment: @user15793316 So I should add a check like : "If this.equals(that) return 0" with equals override

Comment: @user15793316 ok perfect got you thanks!